# My bluetooth adapter turns off by itself and i can't turn it back on, why?

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth mouse and I am using it for a couple of days now, but after a period of time (1-2 hours) my bluetooth of the computer stops and i cant re-enable it. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and i have installed blueman as well, but that didnt work. When bluetooth turns off by itself and i run `rfkill list` i get only this

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

No bluetooth there at all. When i try to run `systemctl enable bluetooth.service` and then `systemctl start bluetooth.service` I am only getting

> Synchronizing state of bluetooth.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
>   Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable bluetooth

And nothing is working. I have to restart the computer in order for the bluetooth to work again. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

upgrading Ubuntu to 18.10 fixed my problem

Comment: btw i still have the same problem in 20.04 :D